# Error exporting animation ffmpeg - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ffmpeg

I'm having issues with exporting an animation using python through anaconda on a Mac. I'm getting the following `RuntimeError`.

```
RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available
```

Looking at other questions, the main options are to install `ffmpeg` via conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

Or designate the path:

```
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'
```

The second option just returns the same `RuntimeError`. The first option returns a separate error:

```
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/person/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1152, in save
writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)

  File "/Users/person/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "/Users/person/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 232, in saving
self.finish()

  File "/Users/person/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 368, in finish
self.cleanup()

  File "/Users/person/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 411, in cleanup
raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(

CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-s', '1600x1302', '-pix_fmt', 'rgba', '-r', '10', '-loglevel', 'error', '-i', 'pipe:', '-vcodec', 'h264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-b', '8000k', '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-y', 'test_text.mp4']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
```

Chasing up this error then refers me back to uninstalling the `ffmpeg` package. But this just leads to the initial error stating `ffmpeg` isn't available.

Comment: Have you tried: https://superuser.com/questions/624561/install-ffmpeg-on-os-x. You may also want to check cocalc.com. It offers are online ubuntu emulator with preinstalled ffmpeg. You can upload a file, perform various operations on it, and then download the modified file.

Comment: Thanks. That was a battle. I now have brew installed but had to insert the correct path in the console otherwise it threw the same error. I'm not sure how many people will find this question useful. If you format your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Homebrew to install FFmpeg and its dependencies. Homebrew is meant for installing packages that don't come preinstalled on a macOS. It installs packages to their own directories and symlinks the files to /usr/local saving you the hassle of designating paths.

You can install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) by pasting the following command on your macOS Terminal.

```
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Following its successful installation, you can install FFmpeg as follows:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Comment: Check the dependencies of ffmpeg before installing: 1 of its dependencies requires python 3.9: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824109/brew-install-ffmpeg-installs-python-3-9/64824279.  This answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64824279/4813038, reminds us to check dependencies :  `brew deps --tree ffmpeg` before installing and screwing up your python links.